# Is there an equivalent to svnlook tree for Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I've been using Mercurial for a school project that requires Subversion. Until now, I've just been converting my repository at the end to run some commands the teacher wants the output from. I've managed to get close-enough equivalents to most of them, but I can't figure out `svnlook tree [path]`. I figure, worst case I can write a Python script to do this, but it would be easier if there was something similar built in. Is there?

For reference, `svnlook tree /some/path` prints something like this:

```
/
  files/
    one_file.txt.
    two_file.txt
  pictures/
    red_picture.png
    blue_picture.png
  README
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not get that exact look out of Mercurial.  You could reformat the output of `hg manifest`, or just run the normal unix `tree` command in your working directory (which you may need to install, but is certainly available on any distro).  Alternately you can use the techniques from [Working With Subversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion) on the Mercurial wiki to shuttle changes back and forth.

Comment: Thanks, the command I ended up using was `hg archive /tmp/myproject && tree /tmp/myproject`.